# In BGE, how do I move an object up with a motion actuator for a few seconds then bring the object back to its original area

Tags: game-engine

[image]I am making a game in which if you press e the character will lift up their shield to block an object. I am using a cube to detect objects so when i press e I want the cube to move up to avoid hitting with an obstacle, giving the illusion that you have blocked the obstacle with your shield. When I use the motion actuator it moves up fine but it just wont move back down automatically to receive another obstacle ahead. Thank you for any feedback.[image: here is the detection cube]

Comment: May I see the logic bricks please?

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: @ReeceAllen you have no logic to make it move back down

Comment: @Scalia What logic bricks would I need to make it come back down after a few seconds?

Comment: Your system right now has no great way to move it back down. You're gonna need to make some changes. I would recommend making an animation for the shield or creating a property that defines its locations. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49114/how-can-i-setup-a-looping-animation-in-blender-game-engine/49115#49115

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24612/how-do-i-play-animations-in-the-game-engine

Comment: @Scalia Thanks, I will take a look at these. Also is there any way to change the physics type of an object while the game is playing?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to play an action that lifts the object.

A simple logic would be to have one sensor that measures when to block (e.g. keyboad sensor on <kbd>E</kbd>).

[image]

Activate an action actuator that plays the action in flipper mode. This means when the blocking request ends -> the action will be played reverse.